# Having trouble setting the icon in MSVC 2008

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, icons

I am making a C++/CLR Winforms application in MSVC 2008, but I can't seem to set the icon.

I have added a .ico file as a Resource (Add->Resource->Icon->Import) and added a line to the .rc file (and fully recompiled, but nothing has changed; it still uses the default icon.

There are no other icons added. I can see and edit the .ico with the in-built icon editor; it has both 16x16 and 32x32 sizes.

What else do I have to do?

[Edit] Just noticed that my icon is correctly showing in Windows Explorer, but not in the application when it runs.

Comment: Windows does do some very annoying icon caching at times - I know that happens with application icons on the desktop anyway. Just in case it's something like this, temporarily change your display settings to a different colour depth (e.g. 16-bit colour rather than 32-bit colour) then change back again - that will refresh the icon cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. :(